# Continuous Deployment with TeamCity

Tags: deployment, teamcity, continuous-deployment

I recently set up a CI server in TeamCity and now want to take it to the next step, continuous deployment.  Basically, we host a suite of restful services and about 3 web applications for each one of our customers.  All customers get 3 environments QA, UAT and Prod.  We want to be able to automatically deploy our builds once our tests pass.  I'm not looking for custom scripting options to do this.  I've seen plenty of those of SO.  What we're looking for is a solutions like UDeploy but at a lower price point.  Is anyone aware of alternatives to UDeploy? Or other Continuous Deployment plugins that work with TeamCity?

Thanks,

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If this is .net you should look at Octopus, it now works nicely with TeamCity.

http://www.octopusdeploy.com/

http://www.paulstovell.com/octopus/octopus-octopack-and-teamcity

Comment: I heard about Octopus on Hanselman's podcast and totally forgot about it.  Thanks for the reminder.  I went to the site and did a bit of digging It looks awesome!  However, I contacted them about 6 days ago and haven't heard back yet so I'm a bit nervous about that.  I'm sure they are swamped but 6 days without any response is a long time for us since we're trying to build a company ourselves.  But other than that the tool itself looks great.  Thanks again.

Comment: As a time saver to others, this requires you to have another step in your build process, creating NuGet packages, and doesn't support WebDeploy.

Comment: The ALM Rangers team also has another option they are working on, it's still in Beta though. https://vsardevops.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 18):

I agree with @Niklas Ringdahl -- I think you're thinking about it wrong.

**You can deploy directly from TeamCity using [MS WebDeploy](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/web-deploy).**

See Troy Hunt's excellent blog series about this:

[Part 1: Config transforms](http://www.troyhunt.com/2010/11/you-deploying-it-wrong-teamcity.html)

[Part 2: MS Build and deployable packages](http://www.troyhunt.com/2010/11/you-deploying-it-wrong-teamcity_11.html)

[Part 3: Publishing with WebDeploy](http://www.troyhunt.com/2010/11/you-deploying-it-wrong-teamcity_24.html)

[Part 4: Continuous builds with TeamCity](http://www.troyhunt.com/2010/11/you-deploying-it-wrong-teamcity_25.html)

[Part 5: WebDeploy with TeamCity](http://www.troyhunt.com/2010/11/you-deploying-it-wrong-teamcity_26.html)

Comment: Or deploy with Ant, NAnt, Maven, file copy... the sky is the limit really. :-)

Comment: Yes you can deploy directly from TeamCity using MSDeploy but Octopus Deploy provide you more than just deploy: it allows you to manage artifact versions, to promote build artifact between environments without re-building etc.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if there's any part of this I don't understand, but I would use TeamCity for that also.

If you have a build configuration to manage your tests, you can easily create configurations for deploy, which are triggered by the success of the test configuration. We handle lots of our deploys that way.

Again, sorry if I'm missing something here...

**EDIT**:

A build configuration in TeamCity can be triggered when another configuration is successfully built: 
[Build triggering in JetBrains documentation](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TCD65/Configuring+Build+Triggers) (Look at "Finish Build trigger")

Or you could use one build configuration with many "Build steps": 
[Build steps in JetBrains documentation](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TCD65/Configuring+Build+Steps)

Each step is run in order, and only if the previous step is successful.

Comment: No you're not missing anything at all.  sorry if I wasn't able to articulate the problem well enough.  If you could post some examples on how to do this with TC that'd be awesome!

Comment: I addes some links to JetBrains documentation of this. Please let me know if you need more guidance.

Comment: @Buzzer: Did you look at the examples? Do you have any more questions?

Comment: I upvoted your answer because although it wasn't exactly what I was looking for, it helped me some.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Another alternative: RedGate has recently updated pricing on their Deployment manager tool: http://www.red-gate.com/delivery/deployment-manager/

If you have 5 projects or less, the tool appears to be free.

Comment: According to their website, RedGate Deployment Manager has been retired and replaced with [Octopus Deploy](https://octopus.com.)

Comment: Looks like the [community edition of Octopus deploy](https://octopus.com/purchase) is roughly the same level of 'free-ness'.

Answer (score 1):

I'm familiar with Nolio ASAP but have no knowledge about its pricing:
http://www.noliosoft.com/product/nolio-automation-center

Answer (score 0):

As a developer for the product, I'll add [BuildMaster](http://inedo.com/buildmaster) to the list of options here. Basically, you can run a basic tutorial to get started deploying from TeamCity (http://inedo.com/buildmaster/extensions/teamcity), then customize your deployment plans to any further environments as needed.